# Mutiply two column values in GoogleAds API V10

Tags: python, sql, api, google-ads-api

typicallyl in sql, you can use * to mutiply columns, but I am getting an error when trying to do so in my query below within GoogleAds API - anyone face this challenge before.

Code:

```
import sys, json, io, gzip, sys, os
from googleads import adwords
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def google_ads_extract(client,customer_id, s3_path,fields,report_type,statuses,date_range, download_version, job_name):
  ga_service = client.get_service("GoogleAdsService")
  search_request=client.get_type("SearchGoogleAdsStreamRequest")
  search_request.customer_id = customer_id
 
  query = """
        SELECT
          segments.date,
          ad_group.id,
          ad_group.name,
          campaign.id,
          campaign.name,
          metrics.impressions,
          metrics.clicks,
          metrics.clicks*metrics.average_cpc as cost,
          metrics.conversions,
          metrics.ctr,
          metrics.average_cpc,
          metrics.cost_per_conversion




        FROM ad_group
        where segments.date BETWEEN 20220427 AND 20220428 
        
        limit 10
        """
             
  print(query)
  search_request.query = query
  
  stream = ga_service.search_stream(search_request)
  
  for batch in stream:
    for row in batch.results:
      print(row)      
  return 1
```

Error:

```
Request made: , Host: googleads.googleapis.com, Method: /google.ads.googleads.v8.services.GoogleAdsService/SearchStream, RequestId: TevDX_z7WYF-AWUZBMVbnw, IsFault: True, FaultMessage: Error in query: unexpected input *.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic operations are not supported in GAQL. You'll need to perform these calculations on the client side after you have downloaded the data.

For your specific example, it might be possible to just use `metrics.cost_micros as cost` instead of `metrics.clicks*metrics.average_cpc as cost`.

Comment: is there a method to download the data? The old version did have one but I cannot find in the new?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean—the example code in your question does download data, no?

Comment: as in download as a csv/json so I can push to s3

Comment: There's a helper function `MessageToJson` in `google.protobuf.json_format` that can convert the returned rows (which are protobuf messages) into JSON. Maybe it could be helpful for your use case.